# SQL Server Parallelism in Execution Plan when connecting via DotNet

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-execution-plan

Can someone explain why there is a difference in execution plans when connecting via DotNet using the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient library, vs running the query from SQL Server Management Studio?
I am running the exact same query in both cases, but the query from DotNet doesn't use Parallelism in the execution plan, while the query from SSMS does.
This is a problem, because without parallelism, the query runs very slow.
It is reproducable.

Comment: Can you post the execution plans? https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: The client used won't be the problem (at least not directly), but there are many other factors that influence query plan generation, and SSMS in particular is notorious for using settings that are by default different from most clients, giving it its "own" set of cached plans. See [Slow in the Application, fast in SMSS?](https://sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: Please post the query, the relevant tables and indexes, and share the query plan using the above link. We can't answer this question otherwise.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.